# Пытаюсь сделать код, который ищет в XML данные и выводит через PHP

Tags: php, xml

Сам ни капли не разбираюсь в работе с XML, да и PHP на уровне чтения и редактирования. Перерыл всё, что мог, и наше, и западное. Перепробовал кучу скриптов - не получается (вероятнее всего из-за кривых рук и отсутствия знаний). Нашел вот такой код, он (наконец-то!!!) выводит на страницу сайта инфу из XML файла.

```php
    <?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("https://varium.kz/test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    echo $xml->offer[0]->price;
    ?>
```

Но вот есть такая загвоздка - мне нужно, чтобы код "видел" на какой странице (товаре) его разместили, чтобы мог получить с неё уникальный идентификатор "Код товара: 695331", по этому идентификатору найти в XML файле нужное значение `<offer sku="695331">` и вывести эти !!! на страницу. Ну и, соответственно, чтобы при изменении цены в XML она сразу менялась на странице.

Скажите, уважаемые, я хоть в правильном направлении ползу? А если кто-то понял суть и ему не трудно дать развернутую подсказку или код - буду очень благодарен.

P.S. уже 3 дня пытаюсь это сделать =(

Я вижу этот скрипт как-то так, но не хватает знаний, чтобы это прописать...

```php
    <?php
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("https://varium.kz/test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        $ищу на странице уникальный идентификатор; (php код, который выводит идентификатор на страницу <?php echo $product['model']?>)
        $ищу по этому идентификатору offer в xml;
        $вывожу значение price, принадлежащий этому offer;
        echo $xml->offer[0]->price;
        ?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133642/discussion-on-question-by---------xml-).

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('yandex_example.yml');

$productModel = '695331111'; //$product['model']

$price = null;
foreach ($xml->shop->offers->offer as $offer) {
    if (isset($offer['sku']) && $productModel == $offer['sku']) {
        $price = (float) $offer->price;
    }
}

// $price - цена offer с sku="695331111"
```

Comment: Андрей, спасибо за ответ! Но у меня не получается запустить код. На тестовой странице остаётся просто белый экран, а на основном сайте выводит кучу ошибок в том месте, где вставляется код. Что я делаю не так? =(